# unique updating millions of document mongodb in batch - node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, aggregation-framework, background-process

I have a collection containing 100,000 to 1 million documents. For simplicity, lets consider each document has these minimum properties with sample values

```
user_id: 'objectId_user_1',
game_id: 'game_id_1',
selection: [
  {name: 'A', _id:'objectId_A'},
  {name: 'B', _id:'objectId_B'}
] // array will have size 10
```

Now, based on their selection of object, i need to run a function which calculates a score using an external data like this.

```
{
  objectId_A: 123,
  objectId_B: 50,
  objectId_C: 77,
  ....
  objectId_Z: 40
}
```

Since everyone will have a distinct `selection` array, thus `score` will also be different. I need to store this `score` value in the respective document.

after update, each document will look like this:

```
user_id: 'objectId_user_1',
game_id: 'game_id_1',
selection: [
  {name: 'A', _id:'objectId_A'},
  {name: 'B', _id:'objectId_B'}
],
score: 385,
processed: true
```

How can I do this effectively. Is it possible to do through aggregate query?

I can think of fetching data in batch and processing and then updating using `node-schedule`. But I hope there are better solutions.

Each of the document is ~1.8 KB in size
My mongo server is relatively small (~2gb ram, 100gb storage)

*I don't mind if the entire thing takes 20-30 mins to process*

Comment: How do you count the score?  based on what?